# How can I indent paragraphs, but exclude certain lines for formatting?

Tags: html, css

so I have been wracking my brain and trying different options to get this to work, but I can't seem to get anything to do what I want.

I am trying to indent the first line of paragraphs on a web page using

```
p {
text-indent: 3em;
}
```

However, I am also displaying information in a formatted manner, and the font needs to be displayed:

**Description:** Pargraph 1.

Paragraph 2...so on.

**Label 2:** ...

I would like to **not** indent the paragraphs that start with the bold-faced labels; because it throws formatting and alignment off and just generally does not look that good.

Is there anyway to stylize the P tag but exclude any tags that are also tagged with B or strong so that only paragraphs that do not start with a bold-faced character/word get indented?

I attempted to use

```
p:not(b)
```

and

```
p:not(strong)
```

but they didn't seem to work, I'm assuming because b and strong are not div ids/classes and won't work?

EDIT:  To clarify, this is for a page on a Tumblr blog. The way Tumblr handles its customization;  the blog itself has its own CSS Style sheet/html that can be edited.  Then, additional pages can be added that can either be made entirely from scratch (losing some functionality because they no longer tie to the css of the main blog) or using a 'standard' layout that pulls and connects it to the css sheet of the main blog.

On the main blog, you can edit the displaced text in boxes and such with the classes as suggested:

```
p class=class name {
css
}
```

But in a standard layout page, the text editor is an extremely simplistic HTML editor; so you cannot specify a specific class for individual paragraphs and all text gets entered as:

```
<p> <strong> Description: </strong>   Paragraph 1 </p> <br/>
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>
```

And it uses strong instead of b for bold; and em for italics.

Comment: It won't work, because, the `p` will never be `b` or `em`. Instead you need to give a class name to the use it

Comment: I see; and is there no way to identify multiple tags and exclude based on the tag? I ask because the way the website is designed, the page does not allow for the use of a class in the paragraph -  the text is  entered in a format that gets translated as <p><b>Text gets bold-faced</b></p>   and I know my css sheet can detect the p, b, i, etc. to apply colors and such; but I can't seem to exclude base don those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below snippet as an illustration of my comment above.

If your `b` or `em` are inside the `p`, then we may need different method. Please share your code for further discussion.

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p:not(.bold) {
  text-indent: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p class="bold">
    Paragraph
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Illo sapiente et expedita dicta vero natus nobis laudantium a voluptatum alias qui blanditiis perferendis, neque, nisi vel quibusdam doloribus id veniam.
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Illo sapiente et expedita dicta vero natus nobis laudantium a voluptatum alias qui blanditiis perferendis, neque, nisi vel quibusdam doloribus id veniam.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem is that the code is being used on the Tumblr website; as part of the themes for some of the pages on personal blogs.  The pages the information is being displayed on does not have it's own css sheet, so to speak -- so the information is entered into a basic html editor.

Comment: Because of this the <b> or <strong> in this site's case, is inside the <p>   like:   <p><strong>Text here</strong></p>

Comment: Question Editted for clarification

Comment: No, but instead you can do one thing. You can specify your `p` as `position: relative` and give `position: absolute` to the elements starting with `b` or `em`, thereby aligning the same to left. But the risk is that, if there are any other `b` inside your `p`, it would cause issue

Comment: I see, well thank you for your time. For as powerful as CSS is, you'd think it would have some more power in certain areas lol.